# Extracting the data item right after a change of Sign

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Consider the following list:

```
list = {{1., -1}, {1.5, -1}, {2., 1}, {2.5, 1}, {3., 1}, {3.5, 1}, {4., 1}, {4.5, 1}, {5., 1}, {5.5, 1}, {6., 1}, {6.5, 1}, {7., -1}, {7.5, -1}, {8., -1}, {8.5, -1}, {9., -1}, {9.5, -1},     {10., -1}}
```

How can I extract the sublist after (or before) the second element in the 2-element sublists changes sign? i.e, I would like to obtain as a result:

```
{{2., 1},{7., -1}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
First /@ Rest@SplitBy[list, Sign[#[[2]]] &]
```

> {{2., 1}, {7., -1}}

or

```
First /@ Rest@Split[list, Sign[#[[2]]] == Sign[#2[[2]]] &]
```

> {{2., 1}, {7., -1}}

Also

```
Pick[list, Developer`ToPackedArray[Unitize[Join[{0}, 
  Differences @ UnitStep @ Transpose[list][[2]]]]], 1]
```

> {{2., 1}, {7., -1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
SequencePosition[list[[All, 2]], {-1, 1} | {1, -1}] // Map[Last] // 
 Part[list, #] &
```

Or similar to @kglr's answer using postfix phrasing:

```
list // SplitBy[#, Sign] & // Rest // Map[First]
```

---

> {{2., 1}, {7., -1}}